# Browser outputs of SVG data URI vary when retrieved by .getPropertyValue(), what to do?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Original CSS:

```
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='scale' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='25' height='25' class='color2 size1' fill='%23666'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('MyID').getElementsByTagName("A")[0];  
var BG_IMAGE = window.getComputedStyle( el, null).getPropertyValue('background-image');
alert(BG_IMAGE);
```

The JS results in the following various browser output (below), I would like to consistently have the output of Chrome. I use the "Optimized URL-encoded" method from: https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris which encodes... <, >, #, any remaining " (like in textual content), non-ASCII characters, and other URL-unsafe characters, like %. This leaves single quotes and spaces.

The question: how do I safely get the CSS background-image in a consistent output between modern browsers [IE11, Edge, FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari]?

Chrome / Opera (ideal output):

```
url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='scale' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='25' height='25' class='color2 size1' fill='%23666'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
```

FF (replaces spaces with %20 and adds \ before '):

```
url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'%20class=\'scale\'%20width=\'100\'%20height=\'100\'%20viewBox=\'0%200%20100%20100\'%3E%3Crect%20x=\'0\'%20y=\'0\'%20width=\'25\'%20height=\'25\'%20class=\'color2%20size1\'%20fill=\'%23666\'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
```

Edge (adds \ before '):

```
url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' class=\'scale\' width=\'100\' height=\'100\' viewBox=\'0 0 100 100\'%3E%3Crect x=\'0\' y=\'0\' width=\'25\' height=\'25\' class=\'color2 size1\' fill=\'%23666\'/%3E%3C/svg%3E')
```

Comment: Why do they have to be the same on every browser?

Comment: I'm creating an SVG background editor. I am retrieving and manipulating data URI's, then outputting optimized `background-image` CSS.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question, unless it produces something that doesn’t work on some browser. Does it?

Comment: If the data URL is not the same, it's not optimized.

Comment: More specifically IE/FF are adding a character before every single quote, and FF is adding two characters for each space in the data URI.

Comment: You Why is that a problem though? I don’t see why anyone should care.

Comment: I'm not the only web designer who is concerned about file size. The link I posted explains a method that reduces the data URI for SVGs by around 20% compared to base64-encoded and fully URL-encoded methods. Edge and FF are undoing those savings. Bulkier code works, but what is the benefit to adding unnecessary characters?

Comment: There are no files here, just data URLs. You've yet to demonstrate that there's any issue here. Have you shown that it's slower? uses more memory? Anything at all that's not just visual?

Comment: These data URI's will be used in CSS stylesheets. Aren't more characters = to more bytes, and thus bigger files size?

Comment: Depends how the browser stores it internally doesn't it? What you see may not be the same as what the browser records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `decodeURI()` sending the svg string(the part after `url('data:image/svg+xml,`) it is consistent on Chrome and Edge. You may try it on Firefox as I don't have it right here.

Comment: I can update my question if it is not obvious, but I am using JavaScript to retrieve the background-image from CSS. At that very point the browser output varies. Running this output string through `decodeURI()`, while helps with the `%20`, it doesn't remove the backslash before single quotes. I am new to JS, so if I am not applying your answer as suggested, could you be more specific where to use `decodeURI()`.

Comment: That is because the output comes in single quotes. So, for javascript to not get lost, the backslash before the quotes are escaping them, they might go away by itself depending on where you use the string.

If it doesn't, you can use `.replace(/\'/g, '"');` so they turn into double quotes unescaped, as it will still be valid svg.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data URI needs to use single quotes to work on modern browsers, according to the article (linked in my answer) describing "Optimizing SVGs in data URIs" because only single quotes are allowed in URLs.

Comment: I think using `.replace(/\\\'/g, "'")` might be what you're looking for then.

Comment: Is it safe? I'm taking CSS data URIs, manipulating them, and re-displaying them on the page. Removing the escapes from the single quotes and replacing the `"%20"` with `" "` will likely do what I want, but seems like I would be overriding a browser's security precautions. My original question is "how do I safely get the CSS background-image in a consistent output between modern browsers"? By the way, I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you're just using them again in the page, there's nothing to worry about as you're not sending it to any server or anything. Yeah, I google'd it a bit and it seems we just need to do those replaces until the browsers behave consistently(never will).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and responses.